# Error while streaming file the second time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the error while streaming a file to the browser, but only on the second through n times.  The first time it works fine.

```
C:\Users\gfinzer\AppData\Local\Temp\BTnADAkZ.pdf. could not be saved because the source file could not be read
```

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the parameters
    string reportName = Utils.ParseStringRequest(Request, "reportName") ?? string.Empty;
    string reportGuid = Session["reportGuid"].ToString();
    string path = Path.Combine(ReportPath(), Utils.GetSessionReportName(reportName, reportGuid));

    using (var fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + reportName + "\"");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileStream.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        StreamHelper.CopyStream(fileStream, Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
    }

}
```

Here is the CopyStream:

```
    public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When exactly is "the second time"? After a postback?

Comment: How does `StreamHelper.CopyStream` work? Could you post the code?

Comment: It is report generation.  This is the second time that I create the report.  I have added the CopyStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but do you need a `Response.End()` call after the `Flush`?

Comment: No problem! It was a guess tbh!